# expand or collapse grouped columns in google sheets using code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheets have finally added the useful grouping feature. I have a many columns grouped into 10 groups. let's say 1-10. I want group 1 and 5 expanded when I change one cell to one value and group 2 and 6 expanded and group 1,5 collapsed when I change the same cell to a different value. Is it possible to expand or collapse the groups with code?

right now, I have to manually hit the plus and minus signs once I want the sheet to display a different set of data.

Comment: About "code" in your question, can I ask you about the language you want to use? For example, if you want to expand and collapse groups when users edit a cell, you can achieve it using ``onEdit()`` of Google Apps Script.

Comment: Yes. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few months Google Apps Script was extended with several methods to handle column and row grouping. See the release notes from April 2018 on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I googled it... couldn't find it... looked through the doc and couldn't find it.